# Understanding bitwise operations and their effects

Tags: c++, windows, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the bit-wise operators in following code:

```
#define BIT8 unsigned char
#define BIT16 unsigned short
#define MEAN_SIZE (sizeof(BIT16) * 32)

void *Alloc16Address(void** pAlignedStart, unsigned long ulBytes)  // ulBytes=2048
{
  void *pBuffer = new BIT8 [ulBytes + 16];
  *pAlignedStart = (void*)((((unsigned long)pBuffer >> 4) << 4) + 16);
  return pBuffer;
}
```

Later this code gives access violation:

```
f(std::ostream& stream) 
{
  BIT16* m_pMeans, x;
  int iSize = 32;
  x = (BIT16*) Alloc16Address((void**)&m_pMeans,MEAN_SIZE*iSize);
  stream.read((char*)m_pMeans, MEAN_SIZE*iSize); // <<<< access volation
}
```

I understand that exhausting the file may generate an error but previously this worked for the **same code and file**, with the only change being moving from my old WIN7 machine to a new WIN10 machine. At least I would like to rule out the bit-wise operation line as the culprit. Can this code by affected by some environment change?

Comment: Neither of the two occurrences of `&` in the code you show denotes a bitwise-and operator. One indicates a reference type (`steam` is a reference to `std::ostream`), the other is an address-of operator (`&m_pMeans` is taking an address of the variable `m_pMeans`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i think OP used `&` just in the sense of "bitwise operations and it's effects" and actually refers to the bit shifts

Comment: what do you mean with "included"? "Included" in the example? That's self-understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing to do with bitwise operators. The problem is that `unsigned long` is only 32 bits on 64 bit Windows. The code probably ran OK on WIN32.

Change:

```
*pAlignedStart = (void*)((((unsigned long)pBuffer >> 4) << 4) + 16);
```

to:

```
*pAlignedStart = (void*)((((uintptr_t)pBuffer >> 4) << 4) + 16);
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. This solved the error, yet the code ran before on 64 bit WIN7 edition...

Comment: *yet the code ran before on 64 bit WIN7*
You just might have been lucky that the buffer overflow didn't affect any used memory.

Comment: @grunt: peakpeak makes a good point - it's also possible that if your addresses are in the bottom 31 bits of your address space then you can also get lucky (I expect the memory layout is different between Windows 7 and Windows 10).

Comment: Yah, [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) might be turned on now.